# Why are property values "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, properties, iteration, undefined

Javascript:

This is my example code below. I use prompt() variables to create string values for each loop.

```
var team = new Object;
team["fwd"] = "forwards";

for (i=1; i <2+1; i++){
      var fwdName = prompt("enter player name");
      team["fwd"]["p" + i] = fwdName;
   }
```

It is my understanding with the above that in each loop, I get user input to read in a value for each new property (that is created by ["p"+i]) to be set to. The fwdName variable is overwritten with each loop.

I use the following to check that I actually put in values that can be used;

```
console.log(team.fwd.p1);
console.log(team.fwd.p2);
```

and I get undefined as output for each statement.

Answer (score 4):

i belive the `fwd` property of your main object should be an object not a string.

`team["fwd"] = {};`